# How to upload file from AngularJS $http service to asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass an uploaded file from the service to the controller. I checked and the file is in the service , but I can not pass it to the controller

```
uploadFile = function (file) {

    var promise = $http(
    {
        method: 'POST',
        withCredentials: true,
        url: self.baseUrl + 'Admin/uploadFile',
        contentType: 'undefined',
        data: {
            file: file
        }

    });
    return promise;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult uploadFile()
{
    try
    {
        var file = Request.Files[0];
        Response.StatusCode = 200;
        return Content("updated");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        return Content("Fail");
    }
}
```

Comment: So, your question is actually "how to upload file from angularjs frontend to [the backend technlogy you're using]", right? Mentioning which backend technology in the tags you're using would be helpful.

Comment: It's asp.net MVC ... you can tell from the code.  I think you might need to use the headers object to set headers for your $http request (eg - ```headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}``` Instead of the way you have it.

Comment: Thank you. When I insert: headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} I am getting 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct header name is ['Content-Type'<sup>1</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and it should be set to the [**primitive value** `undefined`<sup>2</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), not the string `'undefined'`:

```
uploadFile = function (file) {

    var promise = $http(
    {
        method: 'POST',
        withCredentials: true,
        url: self.baseUrl + 'Admin/uploadFile',
        //ERRONEOUS
        //contentType: 'undefined',

        //USE
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },

        data: {
            file: file
        }

    });
    return promise;
}
```

Normally the AngularJS sets the content type to `application/json`. By setting the content type to `undefined`, the content type gets set to the appropriate value by the [XHR API send method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send).

For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Setting HTTP Headers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers)